# how to to set null value to duplicate value in same column

Tags: php, mysql

my current query is

```
SELECT (case when row_number() over (partition by country order by (select NULL)) = 1 then country else "" end) as country,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM tbl_abstract as b 
     WHERE country=abs.country GROUP by b.country) as countrycount,
tbl_company.company_name, COUNT(*) as abstractcount 
FROM `tbl_abstract` abs 
INNER join tbl_company on abs.companynm=tbl_company.company_id 
GROUP by country,tbl_company.company_name
```

and its working fine mysql version 8.0. but i want same result using mysql version 5.6.33 and this above query is not working on older version. i read partition not support on older version.can anyone please help me on this? want result like this->[image] and now getting result like this-->[image]

Comment: Search for mysql row_number simulation.

Comment: It would be useful(to you) if you added sample data as text to the question.